# Postfix and Prefix operators in Java behave differently

Tags: java, operators, prefix, postfix-mta

Based on the Oracle: [Operator Doc Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

The preference of postfix incr and decr operator is higher than prefix operators.

But when I try this example:

```
int x = 1;
System.out.println(++x * x++); // prints 4

x=1;
System.out.println(x++ * ++x); // prints 3
```

If we go as the operators precedence, the output should be : `3 and 3` instead of `4 and 3`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Operands are evaluated left-to-right, always](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7). Precedence is not related to evaluation order.

Comment: ...they're supposed to behave differently.

Comment: @Array  
Please consider accept an answer, it's how a forum works, by give points to those who spend time to answer you ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is only post/pre increment element :

```
(++x * x++);
++x = 1 becomes 2 and use 2 for value
x++ = use 2 for value, and then 2 becomes 3
2*2 = 4
```

---

```
(x++ * ++x);
x++ = use 1 for value, and then 1 becomes 2
++x = 2 becomes 3 and use 3 for value
1*3 = 3
```

---

*pre-increment :* increment the value and use the new one for compute

*post-increment :* remember the old value, used for this calculation, and then increment